# Detect Docker for Windows vs Docker Native inside of WSL2 VM

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I have a use case where I need to detect inside of a WSL2 VM whether the Docker setup is Docker for Windows w/ WSL integration vs Docker just running inside of the WSL VM (say installed directly via `apt` or `dnf`). The networking situation between these two use cases is different because with Docker for Windows WSL integration you cannot reach containers by their IP from the WSL VM. This poses some problems for some dev-tooling that we have and wasn't previously an issue with devs running on Linux-native machines but we've recently run into it now that some devs are using Windows machines with WSL and Docker for Windows.

Any thoughts on how I can do this? Look for specific env vars, mount points etc?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can just stat /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop and see if that exists.